# Unable to combine all csv files using powershell

Tags: csv, powershell

I would like to combine all the csv files in my local folder but it shows empty results. I am trying to take the header of the first file and skip all the headers in the rest of the files in the folder and join them.

```
get-childItem "C:\Users\*.csv" | foreach {[System.IO.File]::AppendAllText
 ("C:\Users\finalCSV.csv", [System.IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName))}

$getFirstLine = $true

get-childItem "C:\Users\*.csv" | foreach {
    $filePath = $_

    $lines =  $lines = Get-Content $filePath  
    $linesToWrite = switch($getFirstLine) {
           $true  {$lines}
           $false {$lines | Select -Skip 1}

    }

    $getFirstLine = $false
    Add-Content "C:\Users\finalCSV.csv" $linesToWrite
    }
```

My end result is that when I open `finalCSV.csv` it shows no results.

Comment: `$lines =  $lines = ...`? But that shoudln't be the problem.

Comment: Have a look on this [link](http://techibee.com/powershell/merging-multiple-csv-files-into-one-using-powershell/2382).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to overwork your solution. Just use Import-Csv and append to an array. Something like this:

```
$a = @(); ls *.csv | % {$a += (Import-Csv $_.FullName)}; $a
```

Works even if the columns are in a different order.